# Css not working in my android mobile browser

Tags: css

The site look perfect when viewed from desktop But when I tried to access in mobile , it doesn't  show  navbar and background image and only load html content and columns . Any suggestion how to fix it.

Comment: Could you post more details here?

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to find a perfect answer without any code or details but one of the things you can do is to add Bootstrap to the website

**So what is Bootstrap ?**

Bootstrap is an open source toolkit for developing with HTML, CSS, and JS but its biggest advantadge is that it comes with responsive elements so you don't have to worry about how it will look on other devices since the Bootsrap elements are already responsive.

One of the easiest way to do it is to add the following code in your code in your "head" section :

```
<head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Now all you need to do is to put your elements (for example your navbar) into Bootstrap classes (and if needed personalize them) so that it comes out properly on all devices

As for how to actually use the bootstrap elements and personalize them here is some documentation :

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/default.asp

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

I hope this help and if not then feel free to give more details about your issue so that I can try to give you a better answer :)

Comment: I am facing issues in my mobile browser . When I open my webpage into my mobile browser  the background image didn't show and only show html content

Comment: And  I used meta tag and  bootstrap link the problem is that . When I open webpage in desktop browser it's perfectly work and  open in mobile browser the page didn't work please do needful

Comment: If you can show me the code html/css I can work on a more concrete solution :) other wise I can't know where is the problem